# using tee command to create time specific log files

Tags: bash, shell, tee

I am using 'tee' command to redirect the log of my shell program into a file.

My requirement is to append the current date and time with the file name.

```
sh sample.sh | tee logfile_$date.txt #sample command
```

Output Log File:

```
logfile_2013-08-22-14.txt  #yyyy-mm-dd-hh format
```

How can i achieve it ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since `date '+%Y-%m-%d-%H'` returns a date of the type `2013-08-21-10` (year-month-day-hour), you can use the following:

```
sh sample.sh | tee logfile_$(date '+%Y-%m-%d-%H').txt
```

For example, let's print `hello` and also store it in a file:

```
$ echo "hello" | tee logfile_$(date '+%Y-%m-%d-%H').txt
hello
$ ls logfile_*
logfile_2013-08-21-10.txt
```

As you see, a file with the name `logfile_2013-08-21-10.txt` has been created at the same time that the string appeared in the screen.

Comment: Thanks I was searching this for a month. :)